# link error while using IAudioSessionManager

Tags: c++, windows, audio, linker

I have a static lib using IAudioSessionManager in one of the methods. The lib build just fine.

I've also setup a console app to quickly test my lib but it refuses to link:
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IAudioSessionManager

Do I need to add some kind of .lib in my linker option? I can't find anything like this in MSDN doc.

I'm using VS2013.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok find out that you cannot use IID_IAudioSessionManager

but have to use __uuidof(IAudioSessionManager)